# Hyperledger Composer Installation Failed

Tags: ubuntu, installation, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm new to hyperledger composer, and is now using ubuntu 16.04 LTS following the official guides. But I encountered some problems, please help me out if possible, thanks!!!

1. I'm connecting it via xshell, how can I get a GUI? I'm not sure how to view the playground demo in a browser.
2. When installing composer CLI tools, the info is:

   > > sudo npm -unsafe-perm install -g composer-cli
   > >     [Failed to check composer --version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WXF4.png)

Can anyone point out the reason?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go the following link to run it with a gui in bluemix.
[composer UI link in Bluemix](https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/login).
Try to import the tutorial network into the bluemix blockchain.
Follow the [steps](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/introduction.html) one by one.

For installing hyperledger composer cli use the command: *npm install -g composer-cli@*

```
ex: npm install -g composer-cli@0.16.3
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can we get a GUI for local test?

Comment: You have to run composer-rest-server.It creates a UI to interact with the rest layer.